# Regex: If the first letter is an X, it should end with either A or B. How do I do this?

Tags: regex

Regex Problem for Password:

- Should Start with either X or Y.
- Followed by an even number (3 digits max).
- And if the password started with an X, it should end with either an A or a B.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: "Regex" is very vague. There are many different regex engines, with different features and syntaxes. You'll need to figure out what language/library/tool you want to use this regex in, and include that information in the question.

Comment: (Also, you should tell us what you've already tried, and where you've gotten stuck. This isn't really a "please do my homework for me" site.)

Comment: @ruakh It was PHP and I managed to do, there's no need to make accessments about someone's question and coming with the "we don't do you homework here" thing.

Anyway, I managed to do it with some help from the responsespeople who actually tried to help with the question, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^(((Y)(([0-9]){0,2}[02468]){1})|((X)(([0-9]){0,2}[02468]){1}(A|B){1}))$
```

- `^` is the beginning of a line
- `()` indicate capture groups
- `|` is or
- `[02468]` is for even numbers
- `{1,3}` is a quantity limiter for a
  capture group (1 min, 3 max)
- `$` is the end of the string

To make this easier, if you're on a Mac, I suggest you download an app called [Patterns](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/patterns-the-regex-app/id429449079?mt=12). Patterns makes it easy to play around with regular expressions and see what's going on without having to wait for server responses when you test on sites like regex101, etc.

Here's what Patterns looks like:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it match a number like 134?  Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: 134 is an even number.  The OP did not say even digits. But that is my interpretation so I could be wrong.

Comment: @Adrian your answer helped me reach my objective, I saw your response and tweked it so I could enter odd digits too, and managed to do it. And now, seeing how you edited your post, I see the tweaks I made were right, so believe me, you helped a lot :)

Comment: `{1}` is useless, `(A|B)` is better written `[AB]` and why all these capture groups? They slown down the process.

Comment: @toto I don't work with regex every day, my friend. I was waiting for jenkins and thought I'd help someone out while I waited. If you've got a better way to do it, you're welcome to post an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.  This is Java but the expression is pretty much vanilla `regex`

- `\\d{0,2}` 0 to 2 digits
- `[02468]` is an even digit
- `$` end of string
- `(?:` start of non-capturing group

```
        String reg = "(?:X\\d{0,2}[02468].*[AB]$)|(?:Y\\d{0,2}[02468].*$)";
        System.out.println("X231swiwiwiA".matches(reg)); //odd number - false
        System.out.println("X232swiwiwiA".matches(reg)); // true
        System.out.println("Y632swiwiwiR".matches(reg)); // true
```

Note. The double slashed are to escape the Java string slash and pass it to the regex engine as a single slash.  You may need to adjust to one slash for your engine.

Comment: Op said maximum of 3 digits, so the `\\d`s should be optional I think: `\\d{0,2}`

Answer (score 3):

If your regex engine supports it, you can use [positive look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like this

```
(?:X(?=.*[AB]$)|Y)\d{0,2}[02468].*
```

-- edit

After reading the updated question, this would be a better approach

```
^(?:X(?=.*([AB]))|Y)\d{0,2}[02468]\1?$
```

It also uses a [back-reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to match the letter captured by the positive look-ahead.

Comment: Well, I like it!  +1

Comment: Nice! It's compact, but I don't use regular expressions frequently enough to know what's going on w/o docs.

Comment: @Diadistis  Unfortunately, your expression matches on any 3 digit value starting with an even digit and ending with an odd digit.  I think it is because the `\d{0,2}[02468]` is not matched but `[02468].*` is matched.

Comment: @WJS I was in the process of updating my answer :)

Comment: i   can certainly relate to that!  :)